# Jquery plugin gif-player

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, gif

Using https://github.com/private-face/gif-player plugin.
Trying to get the player to go full screen with autoplay at startup but having no luck with the fullscreen option, have read the docs but having no luck.

I know I'm calling the option wrong and have tried many different combinations - the last one is below;

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('.gif-player').gifPlayer(){
fullscreen,true}
});
</script>
```

I'm using the test example provided in the zip but not able to go full-screen on page load, help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you calling wrong code,

Right way to call Code;

```
        $(function() {
        $('.gif-player').gifPlayer({
            fullscreen:true                
        });
    });
```

with auto play;

```
$(function() {
        $('.gif-player').gifPlayer({
            fullscreen:true,
            play:true                
        });
    });
```